# PHP in Go. FastCGI?

Tags: php, go, fastcgi

I am writing webserver in Go that will replace existing website. I still need some old PHP scripts. Right now I have lighttpd + fastcgi. So I wish my web server to call PHP as FastCGI.

What is best way to handle it?
I guess I need some Go FastCGI API

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/  - It seems only to support Server side not client.

Comment: I found both the question and the current answer interesting and informative, and I think the answer is supported by "specific expertise".  I don't see the potential for "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion".

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd have to make your own if you want to connect directly to a fastcgi process. Keep in mind though that you still have to run a process manager/spawner anyway, so it wouldn't be a huge leap to just run nginx, too, and have your Go process proxy there for the PHP scripts.

You could also reasonably turn it around and have end-users connect to nginx on port 80 and have nginx proxy requests to your Go process or fastcgi as appropriate. One advantage of that is that then easily can have the Go process run as a different user than root.

Comment: I do not run go as root. I use iptables instead. I use long polling and expect system to support 1000 or 10000 or more concurrent connections. If I put nginx in front then I will have 2 times more connections. I guess it would be expensive. If Go process will connect nginx (lighttpd in my case) then I will have to modify PHP scripts. Otherwise they will detect external IPs as 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Have the Go process talk to nginx to run PHP then. The Go process can add an X-Forwarded-For header and nginx can use that to set the IP address. You can also implement an fcgi "client"; it is not too hard but it will be more work getting done and bug free.